# Laravel 7 migration error. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-7

Try to create foreign key in Laravel 7 but when I migrate tables using `artisan` it gives error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'remote_id' and referenced column 'parent_id' in foreign key constraint 'products_remote_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_remote_id_foreign` foreign key (`remote_id`) references `categories` (`parent_id`) on delete cascade)

My categories table

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id');
            $table->tinyInteger('depth');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))->nullable();
        });
```

My products table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('remote_id');
            $table->foreign('remote_id')->references('parent_id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->string('barcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->text('images')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))->nullable();
        });
```

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?
Thanks for help!!!

Comment: You're trying to link an integer column `integer('parent_id');` to an unsigned bigInteger column `unsignedBigInteger('remote_id');`. The definitions must match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by aynber, for foreign keys to be compatible, they must be of the same type. Your `remote_id` in your products table is an **unsignedBigInteger** while the key you are trying to reference in your categories table, `parent_id`, is an **integer**. To fix this either change `category_id` in your products table to an integer or change `parent_id` in your categories table to an unsignedBigInteger.

**Edit:**

I looked a little more into foreign keys and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54154131/12816127) useful answer on another post. Foreign keys need to have a unique constraint or be a primary key. Since your `remote_id` column is referencing `parent_id` which is neither a primary key nor has a unique constraint, you are getting this error.

The solution given in the other question for adding a unique constraint is running this command(modified for your tables):

`alter table categories add constraint uq1 unique (parent_id);`

Comment: Yap, both of variants

Comment: And it returns the same error message? Do you mind editing your question with the ways you have tried?

Comment: yes of course and i type just integer instead of unsigned

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'products_remote_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'categories' (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_remote_id_foreign` foreign key (`remote_id`) references `categories` (`parent_id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: No problem, mark this answer correct if it works, for future visitors. (And so I know you got it)